# "Upgrading apps" message during boot

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I bought a new MOTO GEN2 2015, showing notification with Android upgrading start Apps.. while switching on the mobile, is any one facing this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add much more detail on exactly what the issue is. From what you've written it is not clear what you've done, what the problem is and/or what messages you're seeing.

Comment: Do you mean Motorola Moto G Gen 2?

Comment: yes in moto gen2

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't an issue.  Some devices running Lollipop seem to show this message very briefly for no real reason.  I would assume that it is checking that AOT compilation has been done for apps you've installed, but I don't really know.  In any case, it's normal.